# SQL server, how to combine rows on certain condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
table1  a     b     c

        1     2     3

        1     2     5

        2     3     4
        ....
```

only combine rows with the same a and b:
Desired result:

```
table2  a     b     c

       1     2     3,5

       2     3     4
       ....
```

How? The real table contains like 15 fields, and want to combine rows base on 5 fields.

Comment: I hope this is for presentation only... Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: When you say combine, are you referring to eliminating rows from one table or the other, or simply for display purposes?